# Stop Android automatically restarting app after crash

Tags: android

On Android 9 the app crashes, the logs show up, but then the app restarts and the logs get lost. Is there any chance to disable this functionality and have it like it was pre 5.0 or whenever they added this functionality?

I can't see the crash because it clears the logs as it restarts. I'm going crazy !

Any solutions ?!

Comment: Go to log-cat and select no filter in right hand side.If you selected the show only selected  application change it to No Filter.It will show your error log even after restart of application.

Comment: The only way an app would automatically restart after crash is if you have a Foreground Service that uses `START_STICKY`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Is there any "native" or "default" way (i'm guessing via intent) to know if the app is coming from a restart and not a manual launch? I'm maintaining a crappy app where I changed the U.I to use lifecycle components and when it crashes, it only shows the UI and the components don't load that. There is a service but I'm not sure how to go about bringing the entire ship down just so the app doesn't restart.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Nevermind. I found it ... there's a setting under `Developer Options`

"Always show crash dialog". So, so frustrating!

[image]

Comment: not working when foreground service is running. any other solution?

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: This rarely works

Answer (score 8):

In Log table Change the value of top left Corner dropdown value from "Show only selected Application" to "No Fillter"

Comment: This is the solution that works for me! I've been struggling with this for at least 4 months and had to search Google with very specific keywords in order to find your post. Thanks!

Comment: It's at top right corner for Android Studio 4.1.2. Just for reference.

Answer (score 6):

You can also find crash in run tab available at the bottom of android studio.

Comment: This solution is working if foreground service is running thanks :)